# what is the fastest CSS display Property for Animating DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom, animation, css

it seem that

```
display: block
```

cause less reflow then

```
display: table
```

also is there any css property that could be set to make sur that changing one dom element won't affect the layout of some other element and thus causing extra repaint or reflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `position:absolute` to the element would take the element completely out of the flow of the page, therefore causing no reflow for other elements.

Comment: I discovered that the best way to change the position of the element while completly avoiding reflow is to use css3 transform Property. Also having position:absolute should not hurt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `visibility: visible;` and `visibility: hidden;`. As the element still takes up space while it's hidden, the impact on the layout is minimal when you show/hide it.